# запятая перед как: "человек, как представитель данной культуры"

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите с запятой!

*Отражение становится все более обобщенным, все более нормативно-культурным, то есть обусловленным рамками тех деятельностей, в которые вовлечен человек, как представитель данной культуры*.

Человек как представитель... не знаю, мне кажется, здесь не нужна запятая...?

Answer (score 2):

Согласен. Здесь "как" в значении "в качестве", запятая не нужна. Если только экзотическая интонационная, но это было бы чересчур для такого текста.

Comment: ))) спасибо! Вы мне круто помогаете!) откуда так хорошо знаете русский язык?

Comment: Сам не знаю. ))) В школе на двойки учился. Но к сорока годам как-то стало получаться. ))) Ну а к пенсии уже начал советы давать.

Comment: ))))) ха-ха) смешно ответил